# Convert BoundMethodHandle to reflection

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

Is it possible to retrieve the member that is being referenced to with a MethodHandle?

```
MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(..., ..., ...);
java.lang.reflect.Method method = convertToReflection(mn); //???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term is “direct method handle”, to emphasize the fact that there is a direct connection to a member of a class. Or as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleInfo.html#directmh) puts it:

> A *direct method handle* represents a method, constructor, or field without any intervening argument bindings or other transformations.

The term “bound” would rather suggest that there are pre-bound parameter values or a bound receiver, which would not match a plain Reflection object anymore.

Java 8 allows to get the member from a `MethodHandle` via [`MethodHandles.Lookup.revealDirect(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#revealDirect-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-):

```
public class Tmp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodHandle mh = lookup
          .findStatic(Tmp.class, "main", MethodType.methodType(void.class, String[].class));
        Method method = lookup.revealDirect(mh).reflectAs(Method.class, lookup);
        System.out.println(method);
    }
}
```

It’s constrained to Reflection objects compatible with the context described by the `Lookup` object you provide, i.e. it will work when trying to lookup the same member via name & type would succeed with that lookup object.

Comment: in my case it was a BoundMethodHandle$Species_L after using MethodHandles.dropArguments and i could retrieve the original DirectMethodHandle using reflection to get the field "argL0"

Comment: Right, `dropArguments` is a transformation which produces a non-direct (“bound”) method handle, which does not support retrieving the member anymore. Getting the underlying direct handle works, but of course, is implementation dependent. Since newer Java versions are going to ban such “deep Reflection”, it’s recommended to search for a long-term alternative…